# CSS Issues with TinyMCE and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, tinymce

Since the release of Chrome Version 25.0.1364.99 including the recent release of Version 25.0.1364.152 when clicking into TinyMCE to edit content, the CSS references seem to be lost and all formatting of the content within the TinyMCE IFrame is lost.

The CSS references can be seen within the IFrame within the HEAD tags.  And content looks fine within the TinyMCE control until you click into it in order to edit the content.  At that point all CSS styles are lost.

Comment: Strange, maybe a Chrome bug. I've seen another Chrome but with some styles being displayed incorrectly. Hopefully fixed soon. If it's nothing you did, check the TinyMCE forum and see if others have the issues.

Comment: Do you use TinyMCE in a specific CMS? I had a similar issue when "CMS made simple" got an update and they changed the referencing of css, especially file references (before: url(../img/imgname.jpg); - after: url([[root_url]]/img/imgname.jpg); - for caching reasons.)